# Is there a reusable error-view like buffer in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I am developing a plugin for emacs that analyses files and reports errors on them. I would like to reuse an existing error-buffer (comparable to the eclipse error-view) that I would only have to feed with the error-data. Is there such a thing in emacs? I know there is a central error-buffer in vim.

Answer (score 1):

`compilation-mode` and `compilation-minor-mode` can make many different forms of error messages (including the kind specified in the [GNU Coding Standards](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Errors.html)) clickable.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I already know compilation mode, but I really would prefer something with a real API to work with. I thought a little about it, and I would like to be able to attach "issues" to an buffer, and the problems buffer should pick them up and present them.